# How do i make my timer restart everytime you lose in my game

Tags: javascript

[the game code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MVFdd.png)

How do i make my timer reset when you lose the game?
here is a link to the game:
https://editor.p5js.org/TobiasR/sketches/dvbIsv7Ah

Im new to programming and just recently started making my own game so any advice on how to make it better is appreciated.

Comment: Hi, In your code, when you use the line :

    s = second();

You are basically using the system clock's seconds. You can't reset it, nor can I go about 59, it will start from 0 after reaching 59, which is probably not what you would want. You can simple create a Timer using basic JS.

Comment: You should include your code as formatted text in your post rather than as an image.

Answer (score 1):

You have used system second in your code instead of that you can use the below code for creating a timer in your application.

```js
let hr = 0, min = 0, sec = 0;
let intervalId = setInterval(() => {
    sec++;
    if(sec === 60) {
      min++;
      sec = 0;
      if(min === 60) {
        hr++;
        min = 0;
      }
    }
    console.log(`${hr}: ${min}: ${sec}`);
}, 1000);
```

**Note**: Don't forget to `clearInterval(intervalId)` when user lose  the game. For using intervalId in other functions you have to declare it globally.